# Distinction between limsup and supremum of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider $(x_n)$ any real number sequence. We can list all the sequence elements in a set $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. In my book I see the following statement

$$ \lim x_n = \sup \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$

Ins't this notation sloppy? I mean, putting all the sequence elements in the set may not be accurate. What if we have something like $x_n = 1$ then the sequence is $(1,1,1,1,...)$ but $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ 1 \}$, just a singleton.

Also, is the notation $\limsup x_n$ to mean $\lim \sup \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$?? As it stands, to me the sup in the first paragraph is unrelated to this limsup notion. Can someone clarify?

Comment: Is $\lim x_n=\sup\{x_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ the actual statement? Did you read thoroughly the context of said statement?

Comment: If the sequence is non decreasing then the statement is correct.

Comment: To answer the question in your title, roughly speaking the supremum is the largest term of the sequence and limsup is the largest term when someone is first allowed to remove any finite number of the terms. The "roughly speaking" qualification is simply due to the fact that there may not be a specific term that achieves the honor of being the largest, like the case with 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is that
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n := \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sup\{a_k\,|\, \, k \in \Bbb{N} \quad \text{and} \quad k \geq n\}\right)
\end{align}
or in more common notation,
\begin{align}
\limsup_{ n\to \infty}a_n &:= \lim_{ n \to \infty} \sup_{k \geq n}a_k. 
\end{align}

Note that for each $n$, we have the set of numbers $\{a_k\, |\,\, k \geq n\} \subset [-\infty, \infty]$. If we take the supremum of this, we get a number $\alpha_n \in [-\infty, \infty]$. I leave it to you to verify that $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \dots$. So, by monotone convergence, the limit exists. It is the limit of this sequence that we're taking:
\begin{align}
\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n &:= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\alpha_n
\end{align}

---

Of course, here, I'm assuming you can allow for infinite supremums, and limits, so that the $\limsup$ always exists in $[-\infty, \infty]$.

Comment: By the way, since $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \dots$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = \inf\{\alpha_n| \, n \in \Bbb{N}\}$, or in more common notation, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = \inf\limits_{n \geq 1} \alpha_n$ (this fact is usually proven as part of the proof in the monotone convergence theorem). Hence, $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup\limits_{k \geq n} a_k = \inf\limits_{n \geq 1} \sup\limits_{k \geq n}a_k$.

Comment: Can you provide any official reference on this notations and the way they are read? For example where can I find out about the notation of supremum when it is written with an index, e.g. $\sup\limits_{k \geq n}a_k$ instead of just $\sup a_k$?

Comment: @MichaelMunta Typically when people write $\sup a_k$ (which to me is a little ambiguous, because "$k$" looks like a free variable when it really shouldn't be) it means $\sup_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \equiv \sup\{a_k| \, \, k \in \Bbb{N}\}$, but $\sup_{k \geq n}a_k$ means $\sup\{a_k| \, \, \, k \in \Bbb{N}, \, \, k \geq n\}$. I don't know if there's any "official reference"; it's just kind of like interpret it in the most natural way possible. You may also see things like this: if $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function and $A\subset X$ then $\sup_{x \in A}f(x)$ means $\sup\{f(x)| \, \, x \in A\}$.

Comment: By the way do you have an error on the first definition? You use $a_n$ on the left side, but then $x_k$ on the right. Shouldn't it be $a_k$ on the right?

Comment: @MichaelMunta yes, my bad, it should be $a_k$ on the right... and it looks like in the middle, the $x_k$ should also be $a_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first statement is not true in general context take $(1/n) $ as an example.

$limsup(x_n) := lim_ {k\rightarrow \infty} sup\{x_n: n≥k\}$ which is the greatest subsequetial limit of $(x_n) $.

Comment: so the limit of the supremum of $\{ x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2},... \}$ But is this a set ? Im confused

Comment: You are taking the range of the restricted sequence. Indeed this is a set.